# How to accept numeric values in cobol using screen section

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

So i'm trying to make a simple program in cobol, using the screen section, that will just calculate the sum of 2 numbers. The compiler i'm using is the OpenCobolIDE. The problem is that i'm getting an error saying that my WS-N1 variable is not a numeric value. Here is the code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.PGM001.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-N1    PIC 9(04).
01 WS-N2    PIC 9(04).
01 WS-SUM   PIC 9(04).
01 WS-DUMMY PIC X(01).
SCREEN SECTION.
01 INPUT-SCREEN.
    02 BLANK SCREEN.
    02 LINE 1  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
    02 LINE 2  COL 1  VALUE "-            INPUT             -".
    02 LINE 3  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
    02 LINE 4  COL 1  VALUE "-(1).NUMBER 1   :              -".
    02 LINE 4  COL 18 PIC 9(10) TO WS-N1.
    02 LINE 5  COL 1  VALUE "-(2).NUMBER 2   :              -".
    02 LINE 5  COL 18 PIC 9(10) TO WS-N2.
    02 LINE 6  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
01 OUTPUT-SCREEN.
    02 BLANK SCREEN.
    02 LINE 1  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
    02 LINE 2  COL 1  VALUE "-             SUM              -".
    02 LINE 3  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
    02 LINE 4  COL 1  VALUE "-(1).SUM        :              -".
    02 LINE 4  COL 18 PIC 9(04) FROM WS-SUM.
    02 LINE 5  COL 1  VALUE "--------------------------------".
    02 LINE 6  COL 1  VALUE "EXIT ->                         ".
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
A-100.
    DISPLAY INPUT-SCREEN.
    ACCEPT  INPUT-SCREEN.

    GO TO A-200.
A-200.
    ADD WS-N1 TO WS-N2 GIVING WS-SUM.

    GO TO A-300.
A-300.
    DISPLAY OUTPUT-SCREEN.
    ACCEPT  WS-DUMMY AT LINE 7 COL 8.
    STOP RUN.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you get a runtime error message in the processing of the `ADD` statement (please edit your post to include the actual message).

I guess this only happens if you don't enter the var with all leading zeros.

To solve this problem with the compiler you use you have to add a `MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-N1) to WS-N1` directly after the `ACCEPT INPUT-SCREEN`.

BTW: If you use the standard windows install of OCIDE you use the following compiler: GnuCOBOL 1.1 (official Mingw package)